# space of continuous functions with compact support

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $Q$ be a topological space, and $X$ the space of all continuous functions $f : Q \to \mathbb C$ with compact support. For $f \in X$, let
$$\|f\|_{\max} := \max_{q \in Q}|f(q)|.$$
Show that $(X,\|\cdot\|_\max)$ is not complete.

ps: I know how to prove it when $Q$ is $\mathbb{R}$. I want a more general proof in a topological way.

Comment: It's not true for arbitrary topological spaces.

Comment: It's not even true when $Q = \mathbb{R}$!

Comment: I know it's not true when Q= $\mathbb{R}$. I want a more general proof without any other restrictions, but just in a  topological way.@Mike F

Comment: You do need some assumptions on $Q$, for instance the proposition holds for $Q$ a singleton.

Comment: It appears that the last three comments are all talking about the *negation* of the statement in the question (i.e., that $X$ *is* complete).

Comment: @EricWofsey: Yes that's right, I didn't read carefully enough. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: When $X$ is a  singleton the space is complete..

Comment: Following on what others have said, if $Q$ is compact then $X$ is also complete. So a general proof with no conditions on $Q$ won't work. It might be helpful to refine the question somewhat and indicate if there are types of spaces or examples of spaces $Q$ that you're interested in showing the result for.